# Find same products named differently in different tables that do not have a common unique property

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, matching, full-text-indexing

I have two tables with products. Each table has same products but named a little different or completely different, eg. ("Broadband Services" vs "High Speed Internet"). As you can see the product is the same, but names are different. 
Ideally I would like to have automated process that would point to identical products just by their names in both of the tables.

There is no Foreign key or anything that could be used as unique identifier in both of the tables.

Please suggest something.

Find same products named differently in different tables that do not have a common unique property

Comment: You'll need kind of a *dictionary* with word or phrase pairs. This you can use to couple them. Depending on the quality and variety of your data this will be quite easy or a hell of work ...

Comment: Thanks a  lot. That is something related to what you just mentioned: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/

Comment: Well, you want to declare content like *Broadband Services* and *High Speed Internet* to be *the same*. There will be no tool on earth which will do this for you... Your link points to FTS, but this is something entirely different.